# Ruby on Railsでサーバー起動に失敗しました

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsを勉強しようと思い
`rails server`でサーバーを立ち上げようとしたら

> FATAL: prematurely zombied

と言われ失敗してしまいました。

ネットで検索してもなかなか見つからないのですが
これはどういったエラーなのでしょうか？
解決策などもあればお願いします

### ■追記

開発環境:

- iMac OSX Elcapitan
- ruby:2.4.1p111
- rails:5.1.3

開発環境構築のために Ruby のアップデートや、 gem で Rails のインストールも行いました。
Ruby のバージョンアップの際にリカバリーモードで `csrutil disable` を実行しました。

参考にしたサイトは、ドットインストールの1「Ruby on Rails」の第二回です。
http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_rails_v3/41802
ここの `rails server -b IPAddress -d` で投稿のエラーが出力されました。

---

`-d`を抜いて実行してみました。
実行されているようなのですが ブラウザでアドレスを打ち込んでもページを開くことができませんでした。 以下実行時の出力です。

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.3 application starting in development on 192.168.10.6:3000
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://192.168.10.6:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

---

以上、よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: もしかして Code School の Zombie を使ったチュートリアルをしていますか？ https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux エラーメッセージで検索するとこちらの質問しか出てこないのは確かに変ですね。

Comment: [GitHub で検索してみた](https://github.com/search?q="prematurely+zombied"&type=Code)ところ、[rb-fsevent](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent) の出すエラーメッセージに同じものがあるようですね……。

Comment: 第三者が問題を再現できるかもしれないので、「rails serverでサーバーを立ち上げようとした」という部分を、1手順ごとに具体的に教えてくださいませんか？　何か参考にしたサイトや書籍があるということでしたら、それでも構いません。質問の下の「編集」から直接追記して頂ければと思います。

Comment: ブラウザに打ち込んだアドレスと、ブラウザに表示されるメッセージを省略せずに追記してもらえますか？

Answer (score 1):

rb-fsevent は、子プロセスとして fsevent_watch というプログラムを実行しています。
この fsevent_watch は、起動時に親プロセスを確認し、もしいなかったら、`prematurely zombied` というメッセージを出力して終了するようです。

rails 起動時に `-d` を付けているので、親プロセスの終了が早すぎるのかもしれません。
`-d` を付けなければ大丈夫かもしれません。
`-d` を付けない場合、rails 起動後、待っててもプロンプトには戻りませんので、
rails を終了するには `kill -9` でなく ctrl+c を入力してください。

上に「親プロセスの終了が早すぎるのかも」と書きましたが、そこまで早いものか? という気がするので、ちょっと自信はありません。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
-dを抜いて実行してみましたが、実行されているようなのですが
ブラウザでアドレスを打ち込んでもページを開くことができませんでした。

以下実行時の出力です
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.3 application starting in development on http://192.168.10.6:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://192.168.10.6:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop

Comment: ブラウザにどのように入力しましたか? また「ページを開くことができませんでした」は具体的にどのような画面になりますか?

Comment: コメントだと改行されないので見難いです。質問内容に追記してもらった方が良いですね。